# A question mark appears on my citation in latex

Tags: bibliographies, citing

A question mark appears on one citation in my latex file instead of the number.
the reference is the following, is there any problem with it?

```
@book{Chung2012non,
  title={Non-functional requirements in software engineering},
  author={Chung, Lawrence and Nixon, Brian A and Yu, Eric and Mylopoulos, John},
  volume={5},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
```

**Update:**
I am using `.bib` file also called `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and `\bibliography{ref}`, I cite the reference by `\cite{Chung2012non}`, the citation appears like this [?]. The reference doesn't appear in the references list. Actually, I do all my citations and references by the same way all of them worked without problems.

Comment: Assuming you employ the `biblatex` package, did you also run `biber`, followed by one more `latex` run?

Comment: @Mico Yes I am employing 'biblatex', I did not use  'biber'. Actually all my citations in the same file except the one I mentioned work without problems.

Comment: Let me guess: you added the citation of the `Chung2012non` entry last and haven't re-run biber since. Do see if running biber, followed by one more latex run, makes a difference.

Comment: If you are getting a question mark instead of a citation (and not say the entry key in bold), then it is more likely that you use a BibTeX-based bibliography setup instead of `biblatex`. But this is speculation and it is hard to help you properly if we have to guess what you are doing. Please tell us which bibliography/citation packages you are loading, how you generate your bibliography and how you cite. This is best done by sharing the relevant code (and as little other code as possible) in a short example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: @moewe I have added an update

Comment: Did you ensure your .bib file is called "ref.bib"? If not, your \bibliography{ref} should be updated to \bibliography{file_name_here}

Comment: Your update confirms that you are using classical BibTeX and not `biblatex`, so I have retagged your question. It does not show a complete example document, so we can't test any code. It is possible that you did not run BibTeX as required (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), but there is a number of other factors (errors reported by BibTeX) that could be relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update you are using `bibtex`. Compile twice then run `bibtex` and then compile twice again.

[image: a]

Try this code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}

@book{Chung2012non,
    title={Non-functional requirements in software engineering},
    author={Chung, Lawrence and Nixon, Brian A and Yu, Eric and Mylopoulos, John},
    volume={5},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    Some text \cite{Chung2012non},  

    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{ref}
    
    
\end{document}
```

If the file is named MAIN.tex, after running `bibtex` you should see in the console

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "MAIN"

bibtex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 22.3)
The top-level auxiliary file: MAIN.aux
The style file: unsrt.bst
Database file #1: ref.bib
Process exited normally
```

**UPDATE** To use `biblatex`  on  Overleaf load this code in a new project and recompile.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}       
\addbibresource{ref3.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{ref3.bib}

@book{Chung2012non,
    title={Non-functional requirements in software engineering},
    author={Chung, Lawrence and Nixon, Brian A and Yu, Eric and Mylopoulos, John},
    volume={5},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    Some text \cite{Chung2012non}.  

    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am working on latex online (overleaf), how can I run bibtex??

Comment: @Eng.sh Try my code in Overleaf. Start a new blank project, copy and paste the code and recompile. They will do all the work for you.

Comment: Disp Your first and second code worked on an empty project put it still does not work in my project!? :(